# Tensorflow : can not create dataset with corresponding label using Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

My dataset contains `features` and `labels`, eg.

```
features, labels = (np.random.sample((5,2)), np.random.sample((5,1)))
```

which means there are 5 data elements in this dataset (there are 5 rows, every row is a 2-dim feature and 1-dim label).

I use `tf.data.Dataset` to create a dataset with this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
features, labels = (np.random.sample((5,2)), np.random.sample((5,1))) 
print("feature : \n", features)
print("labels : \n", labels)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()            
x, y = iter.get_next()                                       
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
    print("element:\n", sess.run(x), sess.run(y))
```

I use TF1.5 , Windows 10. Then I get the result:

```
feature :
 [[0.10261779 0.28041519]  # feature0
 [0.91091857 0.95644642]   # feature1
 [0.77542043 0.49631646]   # ...
 [0.33241678 0.28630983]
 [0.39095336 0.76686785]]
labels :
 [[0.54097027]             # label0
 [0.99022349]              # label1
 [0.87510303]              # ...
 [0.07331254]
 [0.10868335]]
element:
 [0.10261779 0.28041519] [0.99022349]
```

When I create the dataset, I hope the feature0 `[0.10261779 0.28041519]` corresponds with label0 `[0.54097027]`. But using the code, the feature0 `[0.10261779 0.28041519]` corresponds with label1 `[0.99022349]`. The order is wrong. I don't know how `get_next` actually works.

I wonder if there is any method that can output the feature and label in order by using the tensorflow Dataset API.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that by running `x` and *also* running `y` separately you are advancing the iterator twice. That is: When calling `sess.run(x)` the first element of `features` is returned and the iterator is advanced. Then calling `sess.run(y)` will return the *second* element of `labels`, since both `x` and `y` are based on the same iterator. If you were to call `sess.run(x)` again, it should return the *third* element of `features` and so on.

I would suggest that you rewrite your code like so, for example:

```
...
next_batch_op = iter.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    feature_batch, label_batch = sess.run(next_batch_op)
    print("element:\n", feature_batch, label_batch)
```

This will only run the iterator *once* and give you access to corresponding features/labels.

As an alternative, I just tried the following and it seems to work:

```
...
x, y = iter.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print("element:\n", sess.run([x, y]))
```

The difference to your code is that we run `x` and `y` together in a single `run` call. However I find the first solution more clear.